Using Selenium-wire with a chrome browser opened through command line using proxies loaded from file
Trying to use proxies and selenium-wire with an exsiting browser to capture requests. It works when not using the proxies but when i add an argument to the command line it doesn't capture any requests. Proxies also work without capturing requests.
Command to launch the chrome browser:
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9231 --proxy-server=localhost:12345 --user-data-dir="path/to/chromeprofile" --load-extension="path/to/proxyfiles"
Example code:
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

links = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.twitter.com/']

service =  Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9231")

sw_options = {"port": 12345}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,seleniumwire_options=sw_options)
    
for index, link in enumerate(links):
    driver.get(link)
    
    for request in driver.requests:
        print(request.url)

driver.quit()

Also, the proxy files that the chrome command is pointing to is:
background.js
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "HOST",
            port: PORT
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "USERNAME",
            password: "PASSWORD"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);

manifest.json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}

Thanks for any help in advance.
